# Should /usr and /home be on different partitions?

Tags: directory-structure

In studying for the lcpi exam, I met the following statement.

> If multiple disks are available it is good practice to also have the /usr and /home directories on different partitions. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LPI_Linux_Certification/Design_Hard_Disk_Layout

For desktop workstations, it makes sense to put your home directory on a separate drive or partition.

I've loged into a lot of linux servers, and I have never seen the system admin put these folders on separate partitions.

**Is is common practice to separate these folders on linux servers?**
**What reasons might you separate /usr and /home?** (Besides making reinstalling easier).

Comment: You might want to make `/usr` read-only, or make it an NFS share across multiple installations.

Comment: @JMoore thanks for the insight. Do you also have a swap partition? If so, do you place it at the beginning or end of the drive. See my other question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84453/what-is-the-purpose-of-multiple-swap-files

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The 3 primary reasons you would create these as separate partitions are as follows:

1. performance
2. isolation
3. security

#### Examples

- By separating `/home` you can put this data on a shared network disk so that when UserA logs into servers in a given domain, their `/home/$USER` will be a single copy that follows them from machine to machine. This is typically done using NFS and automounts (aka. `autofs`).
- By putting `/usr` data on it's own partition, it can be mounted read-only, offering a level of protection to the data under this directory so that it cannot be tampered with so easily.
- Some additional reasoning for isolating `/usr`, is for making it easier to deploy identical systems, these partitions can be prepared one time and then replicated across systems more easily.
- Also separating the data out can make it easier for backup cycles.
- Finally separating volatile directories such as `/home` can protect a system from having it's primary disk fill up by either an accidental or malicious user.

Over the course of my 15+ years of doing this I've only ever seen `/home` separated (as a network share via NFS) and the `/boot` and `/var` directories as being isolated as separate partitions. Outside of some esoteric Solaris boxes I can't recall ever seeing a Linux system having a separate `/usr` - and note that if you don't have `/usr` mounted before `init` starts, your system will break in esoteric and silent ways.

Comment: The difference with Solaris is correlation without causation. In the early 1990s, splitting off `/usr` was often a good idea, and Solaris was pretty common while Linux was barely starting. As Linux took over, splitting off `/usr` was becoming obsolete.

Comment: IIRC debian-installer, if you select autopartitioning and select the option to split the most folders, will put `/usr` on a separate partition (along with `/home`, `/var`, `/etc` (I think), `/boot` and one or two others that I can't remember

Comment: Performance? making different partitions from one disk doesn't offer better performance but creating partition from different disk can.

Answer (score 11):

Putting `/home` on a separate partition is fairly common. That typically splits system files (`/`) and user files (`/home`). The two filesystems may have different performance trade-offs, different backup policies, different quotas, different security policies, etc. Also this way the OS can be reinstalled or reimaged independently of the user data. Splitting `/home` is a good idea both for single-user workstations and for multi-user systems that store user files. I'd only keep `/home` on the same partition on a server that has no user files beyond the administrators' configuration files (but there might be a separate partition for whatever that machine is about — `/var/mail`, or a database, etc.), or on a quick-and-simple installation especially on a laptop which isn't going to be rebalanced to use a second disk.

Putting `/usr` on a separate partition used to be common, back when the OS used a large amount of disk space (say, 300MB out of 1GB). This partition could be made read-only, might be shared over the network. Making `/usr` read-only had the advantage that in case of a power loss, it wouldn't need an fsck. Nowadays all major filesystems use a journal and don't require any lengthy fsck, and disk sizes have increased a lot more than OS sizes — 30GB out of 1TB is peanuts, so it doesn't need to be shared. There is no good reason to split `/usr` from the rest of the system (`/bin`, `/etc`, `/var`, …). If you see advice to split `/usr`, it's grossly obsolete.

Comment: 30GB out of a 128GB SSD is _not_peanuts though...

Answer (score 9):

It is common to separate `/usr` and `/home`. There are a number of
reasons for this. Here are a few:

**Encryption**

Although encrypting the contents of `/usr` can have some benefits, it is common
to dedicate full encrypted partitions to `/home` directories and leave `/usr`
unencrypted.

**Different drives**

I am currently using a laptop that has a small SSD and a large hard drive. The
root partition, which includes `/usr`, is on the SSD. `/home` is on the hard
drive. SSDs wear down relatively quickly as they are written to. Putting
volatile directories such as `/home` and `/var` on the SSD would decrease its
lifespan significantly. Putting my root partition on the SSD decreases my
machine's boot time.

**Security**

It is common to mount `/home` directories with the `nosetuid` option. This
option disallows the execution of setuid files on a mount. Setting this option
makes it more difficult for users to hide away root-owned setuid shells.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did not know about nosetuid. Sure enough, I was able to run a script as root after finding this blog http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html

Comment: Putting `/usr` in a different partition can actually disrupt the `init` process, which will usually be looking for files there, when it might not have been mounted yet.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the root should be on the SSD, to decrease boot time, and /usr and /home should be on the SSD because they get a lot of writes

So what should go on the HDD?

Answer (score 2):

another reason I have found is due to filesystem optimizations. /usr includes shared objects and some other common resources used during runtime by applications so you may want to separate it to put a filesystem better fit for frequent use. Likewise with /home you may also use it for a filesystem well suited for large data